# Using drand48_r as random number generator in C

Tags: c, macos, random, openmp, gnu

So i've been writing some applications in C and using OpenMP for parallelization. I implemented a Monte-Carlo Pi estimate and found that the normal rand() function is not reentrent and thread-safe. The recommendation is to use the drand48_r option.

Now here is the problem, my application compiles fine on Linux eg. Ubuntu, Fedora and CentOS but does not compile on Mac OS X. The compile error on OS X is.

> simple.c:7: error: storage size of ‘randBuffer’ isn’t known

The code used as the simple example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  double x;
  struct drand48_data randBuffer;

  srand48_r(time(NULL), &randBuffer);

  drand48_r(&randBuffer, &x);

  printf("Random number: %f\n", x);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I read up about it and I found a note in the man pages that,

> These functions are GNU extensions and are not portable.

Here is a link to it: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/drand48_r.3.html

So I have a number of questions;

1. What are GNU extensions and what makes it non portable?
2. What alternatives do I have for random number generation on OS X that is also thread-safe?

Well that is about it.

The example is compiled with gcc as,

> gcc simple.c -o simple

Comment: Note that using `time()` as your random seed isn't very random.  This might not matter for your application, but at least take note of the fact that if two processes run in the same second, they'll get the same sequence of random numbers because they use the same seed (time).

Comment: Yeah I usually combine a SEED value with the id of a thread. In this example I omitted the OpenMP code for simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see the gain of using `drand48_r` over `erand48`. `erand48` has the same type of random generator as `drand48` but compared to that receives the state of the random generator as a function parameter, so it perfectly does the job.

The `_r` extensions store the result in place (the second parameter) and return an error code that is always guaranteed to be `0`. I don't see much use in all of this. I'd stick to the POSIX interfaces (in particular `erand48`).

Comment: What's the purpose of an error code that is guaranteed to be 0? Why would anyone check this code if it's always the same?

Comment: @this.lau_, all good questions. You'd have to ask the GNU people what they were thinking.

Comment: @laurent There is a rough check on the arguments, and -1 might be returned (despite the *man*). See the [code source](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/drand48_r.c.html)

Comment: I can see one advantage that `drand48_r` might have. The glibc implementation of `erand48` is not thread-safe, despite what the POSIX standard says (and it says so in the man pages). See https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10320

Answer (score 4):

Use the standard re-entrant functions from `<stdlib.h>`.  They simply pre-date the ubiquitous `_r` suffix, so their names are:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>

 double drand48(void);

 double erand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);

 long jrand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);

 void lcong48(unsigned short param[7]);

 long lrand48(void);

 long mrand48(void);

 long nrand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);

 unsigned short *seed48(unsigned short seed16v[3]);

 void srand48(long seedval);
```

The `erand48()` function takes a data structure (actually, an array of 3 unsigned shorts) as its state.  So, you can implement `drand48_r()` for Mac OS X by bundling that into a locally defined `drand48_data` structure and making `drand48_r()` call `erand48()`, or you can go portable and use [`erand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/erand48.html) which is defined by POSIX and has been available since the 1980s on most Unix systems.  Personally, I'd go for portability, but writing a simple `drand48_r()` is also straight-forward except for sorting out which header declares it.